# VLAN Routing for VOIP

Tags: vlan, voip, hp-procurve, aruba

Confession first - my networking skills are not massive but I'm learning fast!

We have three VLANs (for the sake of this question - there are actually more but not relevant to the posting). These are:

- VLAN 5 Management
- VLAN 6 VOIP
- VLAN 10 Client

I have a new switch (HP Aruba 2920). This is connected to the access layer switch at port 1/42 (access layer) and port 1 (new switch).

I have port 1/42 on the access layer tagged on VLANs 6 and 10 and untagged on 5. Port 1 on the new switch has the same VLANs tagged and untagged.

Into port 2 of the new switch I have plugged the new IP Phone which going in. Port 2 is then tagged on 6 and untagged on 10.

Into port 3 of the switch I have plugged a client pc. I have untagged port 3 on vlan 10.

Now, my issue is this - regardless of whether the PC is plugged into port 3, or into the passthrough data port on the phone, it refuses to connect to the client network.

I have had two people look at this who have much better networking skills than I do, but they can't see any issues.

To confuse things further, I have a number of netgear switches hanging off the access layer switch, all configured the same way (untagged on 10, tagged on 6), and these work fine. The only difference is that on those switches i manually set the ports PVIDs to 10 on these netgears.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

EDIT - Forgot to mention, I have enabled the 'voice' parameter on vlan 6 on both the access layer and new switches.

Comment: PVIDs seem to be the key issue. On an interswitch trunk connection you need to stick to the simpliest scheme. It's unclear from your post why do you need PVIds at all. Furthermore, PVIDs require more understanding than just 802.1Q standard itself. I'd say *get rid of PVIDs*, but this may me a destructive advice.

Comment: And finally, your question lacks a graphical representation. Even drawn by hand. This primarily is needed for your own understanding.